# ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory failing on .Net-Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, zip

I have a .Net-Core project that worked fine on 1.1 but is now failing on 2.0.  The problem is happens when I try to unzip a zip archive with `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` (from `System.IO.Compression`).  I get one or two files out but then it throws an exception with the message:

```
The process cannot access the file '<path to file>' because it is being used by another process.
```

As far as I can tell there is no other process that could possibly be using that file as it has just been extracted.  It is actually present on the disk when I get the error.

The stack trace is:

```
at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.OpenHandle(String fullPath, Boolean asDirectory)
at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.SetLastWriteTimeInternal(String fullPath, DateTimeOffset time, Boolean asDirectory)
at System.IO.Win32FileSystem.SetLastWriteTime(String fullPath, DateTimeOffset time, Boolean asDirectory)
at System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(String path, DateTime lastWriteTime)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToFile(ZipArchiveEntry source, String destinationFileName, Boolean overwrite)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(ZipArchive source, String destinationDirectoryName, Boolean overwrite)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName, Encoding entryNameEncoding, Boolean overwrite)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(String sourceArchiveFileName, String destinationDirectoryName)
at FunctionDataStore.PackageManagement.InstallPackage(String pkgFile, String pkgDir) in D:\Projects\Momo\UserPlatform\FunctionDataStore\PackageManagement.cs:line 250
```

I can go back to 1.1 for the time being but I need to move to 2.0.

Does anyone know what might be causing this exception and what I can do about it?

**Added: 27 Nov 17**

I thought I had the answer after a reboot.  But now the problem remains no matter how many times I reboot the system.  There is some problem with .NET Core 2.0 and `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`.  I have verified that no other process is actually using the extracted files when the error happens.

**Addendum: 207 Nov 17**

Since the stack trace shows `ExtractToDirectory` is failing on the `SetLastWriteTime` call, and I don't really care about the timestamps on the files, I replaced the `ExtractToDirectory` call with the following:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(pkgFile, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        var filename = pkgDir + "\\" + entry.FullName;
        var fileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fileDir);
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int numbytes;
            var stream = entry.Open();
            while ((numbytes = stream.Read(bytes, 0, 1024)) > 0)
            {
                writer.Write(bytes, 0, numbytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `pkgFile` is the zip file to be read and `pkgDir` is the directory to extract to.  This seems to work without problem.

I still don't know why the `SetLastWriteTime` is failing in `ExtractToDirectory`, though.  But this workaround seems to be sufficient for my needs.

Comment: Hmm, no, this is an environmental problem.  First place to always start: disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant, if that were the case then why would it work in .Net Core 1.1?

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation.  Most evident by realizing that the .NETCore version does not change by rebooting your machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Agreed.  But it consistently *does* work for NETCore 1.1 and it consistently *doesn't* work for .NETCore 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can find which process is using your file to find root of error. to find which process is using your file download [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

1. run process explorer
2. press ctrl+f
3. type name of your file
4. this way you can find and kill process using your file